# Class Names in C# (English vs Intellisense)

Tags: c#, naming, convention

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to write C# code.

How should I name my classes? In a  "English-friendly" way, or in a way thats more IntelliSense- friendly.

For instance, I have a interface called
`IColorComparer`. And a few classes that implement that interface:

`QuadraticColorComparer` vs `ColorComparerQuadratic` 
`DefaultColorComparer` vs `ColorComparerDefault`
 `TrauerColorComparer` vs `ColorComparerTrauer`

**Question: Is there a official naming convention for Classes in C# / VS? Does it take tools like IntelliSense into account?**

Comment: The "standard" is completely up to you (if this is a personal project) or your employer (if this is a work project). However, general consensus would be to name it something useful.

Comment: Now it's not opinion-based, but it's still poorly researched. Google "naming conventions C#" and you will find more than enough information.

Comment: Resharper will make your intelli-sense pull up all of those as suggestions when you type in "ColorComparer" regardless of whether the differentiator is at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links provided by Microsoft regarding the naming conventions in C#

General Naming Conventions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx

Capitalization Conventions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx

Overall Guidelines for naming

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is another link provided by "dofactory" for C# coding standards

http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards

Answer (score 1):

It usually makes sense to put the differentiator at the *start*. For example:

- `TextReader` / `StreamReader` / `StringReader`
- `Stream` / `FileStream` / `MemoryStream` / `NetworkStream`

It's like having an adjective to provide more detail: "the red book, the blue book".

One alternative option is to avoid exposing the classes themselves, and instead have:

```
public static class ColorComparers
{
    public static IColorComparer Quadratic { get { ... } }
    public static IColorComparer Default { get { ... } }
    public static IColorComparer Trauer { get { ... } }
}
```

Then you'd just use it as:

```
IColorComparer comparer = ColorComparers.Quadratic;
```

Does anything else really *need* the implementation details? The implementations could even be private nested classes within `ColorComparers`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule for such naming convention. But of course  there are coding standards in c#. Please refer below link which indicates naming conventions standards by Microsoft:
[Microsoft naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For your questions answer I would suggest you to use friendly names and more convenient names for classes. For example use

```
public class ColorComparer
```

Or

```
public class CompareColor
```

Use names that is more friendly to read and understand which will reduce your ans other developers time as well and also help in reducing maintenance cost.

You can ask me your doubts further.

Happy coding